# Figure out total one-way permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Check out the given sets:

```
1 => [
    a,
    b,
    c,
],
2 => [
    x,
    y,
    z,
],
3 => [
    i,
    o,
]
```

I need to adhere to my `1, 2, 3` order and determine the total permutations. So, here's the result:

```
a, x, i    a, x, o
b, x, i    b, x, o
c, x, i    c, x, o

a, y, i    a, y, o
b, y, i    b, y, o
c, y, i    c, y, o

a, z, i    a, z, o
b, z, i    b, z, o
c, z, i    c, z, o
```

...that's `18`. How can I calculate this? At first, I thought `(3 x 3) + (3 x 3) + (2 x 3)` by that's obviously wrong. Clearly, maths is not my forte - so what am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just $3\times 3\times 2$ - you have $3$ ways to make a choice from set 1, $3$ ways from set 2 and $2$ ways from set 3, and the three choices are independent so you just multiply the numbers.

This is the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) for combinatorics.

Comment: That's awesome! As always, staring me in the face.